# C# OleDb select query throws missing operator exception

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm currently connecting to and working with a MS Access database. I can do a generic select * query fine, so I am connected to the db, but when I try to select using parameters it throws a missing operator exception.

```
string selectStatement = "Select ID from pages where page_title = ? limit 1";
string title = Request.QueryString["pagetitle"];

OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand(selectStatement, conn);
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@p1",OleDbType.VarChar);
selectCommand.Parameters["@p1"].Value = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(title);
OleDbDataReader selectResult = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The error I get is on the ExecuteReader line:

`Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'page_title = ? limit 1'.`

I've tried using @p1 inside the query, as well as the current ?. I've tried adding the parameters different ways, including removing the @ in the parameter name. Nothing seems to work. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no `LIMIT` clause in MS Access.

And, parameters should be named, `@p1` in your case, instead of `?`

I haven't worked with Access for years, so I might be wrong, but instead of `LIMIT`, try this:

```
Select TOP 1 ID from pages where page_title = @p1
```

Also, if appropriate, consider this advice:

MS Access isn't quite the right DBMS to handle websites (I suspect in your case it's a website). For an alternative file-based database management systems, check [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and [FirebirdSQL](http://www.firebirdsql.org/). Both have a lot of tools you can use for GUI, like SQLite Maestro, and respectively IBExpert.
Queries are more flexible in those DBMS.

Comment: Legit? That stinks xD But this solves the question. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Also, this isn't for a website. I'm doing some local automated tests, so no one but me will ever see this. I generally work in PHP/MySQL but I can't install those on this machine, so this whole thing is kind of kludgey (took me 4+ hours to finish this in C# when I could have done it in 20 mins!). I also can't install any other DBMSes on this machine. So my options were limited =)

Comment: Still, if you ever need something like this again, try FirebirdSQL. No install needed, just a pile of libraries copied in your application folder. And you'll be able to do queries like `SELECT FIRST 10 SKIP 20 * FROM table`. You can't "skip" rows in a lot of DBMS (Access is one of them), there is always a more complex way of placing this in the `WHERE` clause, like `... WHERE rownum between 21 and 30` or something.

Comment: Note that Jet/ACE TOP N will return ties, so choose your ORDER BY appropriately. Of course, TOP N is meaningless without an ORDER BY.